# probablity function of $XY+Z$ if $X,Y,Z\sim_{i.i.d} Bern(p)$

Tags: statistics, random-variables

The question asks why would $T = XY+Z$ not be a sufficient statistic for $X,Y,Z \sim_{i.i.d} Bern(p)$ As I try to check $\frac{\mathbb{P}(X,Y,Z,T=t)}{\mathbb{P}(T=t)}$ I cannot figure out what $\mathbb{P}(T)$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T$ is not sufficient. To show this it is not necessary to derive the whole conditional distribution. A counterexample is enough

$$f_{X,Y,Z|T=0}(0,1,0|0)=\frac{\mathbb{P}[X=0;Y=1;Z=0;T=0]}{\mathbb{P}[T=0]}=\frac{(1-p)^2p}{(1-p)^3+2(1-p)^2p}=\frac{p}{1+p}$$

As you can see the conditional distribution (for this example) still depends on $p$ thus $T$ is not sufficient.

You can find other counterexamples or, as an exercise, all the distribution.

---

EDIT, answering to you comments

- To calculate $\mathbb{P}[T=0]$ observe that it is attained only in the following cases

$$(X,Y,Z)=\{(0,0,0);(0,1,0);(1,0,0)\}$$

- The conditional distribution is the discrete one defined on the above 3 realizations wiht the following probability, respectively:

$$\left\{ \frac{1-p}{1+p} ; \frac{p}{1+p} ; \frac{p}{1+p}\right\}$$

Comment: but out of curiousity, what would such distribution look like?

Comment: @smaillis : I found the same example here http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/446/Introduction%20to%20the%20theory%20of%20statistics%20by%20MOOD.pdf, Example 18 on page 302